# phalcon form add options

Tags: php, phalcon

I have a problem with phalcon form. I added a form but i can not add options like

```
[
'id' => 'login-form',
'class' => 'form form-x',
'data-form-style' => 'dynamic, rootable, hash',
'data-encrypt' => 'false'
]
```

I want to add all of them which called `setuserOption` in phalcon document but I can't do that.

```
 //form add user options 
 $this->setuserOptions(
    [
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'class' => 'form form-x',
        'data-form-style' => 'dynamic, rootable, hash',
        'data-encrypt' => 'false'
    ]
 );

//my form
$this->setuserOptions([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'class' => 'form form-x',
    'data-form-style' => 'dynamic, rootable, hash',
    'data-encrypt' => 'false'
]);

}

//this is volt ( form.options is written by me .how can i use this options )
{{ content() }}

{{ form('login/login', form.options) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.label('username') }}
        {{ form.render('username', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.label('password') }}
        {{ form.render('password', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.render('submit', ['class': 'btn btn-primary btn-large']) }}
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your Volt code where you render the form?

Comment: I am curious. If you output `form.options`, what does that give you?

Comment: it gave me error this not find options property ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Tag.html), you can add properties to your form tag like this:

```
<?php
 echo Phalcon\Tag::form(array("posts/save", "method" => "post"));
```

or with the Volt syntax:

```
<?php
 {{ form("posts/save", "method": "post") }}
```